# How come, when I'm using Javascript to absolutely position something, its "left" and "top" properties always go to 0px?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to take elements that are statically or relatively positioned and absolutely position them relative their parent container without changing their physical location on the screen.

Here is my approach:

```
function changePosition(element){
  var instance = {};
  instance.element = element;
  instance.parent = instance.element.parentElement;
  instance.dim = instance.element.getBoundingClientRect();
  instance.parent.dim = instance.parent.getBoundingClientRect();
  instance.element.style.left = instance.dim.left - instance.parent.dim.left + "px";
  instance.element.style.top = instance.dim.top - instance.parent.dim.top + "px";
  instance.element.style.position = "absolute";
}
changePosition(document.getElementById("thing1"));
changePosition(document.getElementById("thing2"));
```

The HTML:

```
<div>
  <input id="thing1" />
  <input id="thing2" />
</div>
```

On JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oumt0nkv/2/

Without the `position = "absolute"`, it calculates and applies `left` and `top` as expected. However, when I add that line back in both the `left` and `top` get set to `0px`.

If I explicitly use `100px` instead of variables for the `left` and `top` values, it works as expected.

I don't know why this is happening. If the `position = "absolute"` line was before the lines setting `left` and `top` I might understand it. This way, it appears some of these lines of code are happening asynchronously?

This is occurring in both Chrome and Firefox. Thank you!

Comment: @MrLister Oops! I may have made a typo. I just added a link to a JSFiddle that includes the functioning not-functioning code. :) Sorry about that!

Comment: Yes, I see; I should have refreshed my window.

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements are positioned with respect to their closest positioned (i.e. non-static) ancestor. Have you tried setting position:relative on the div in your example?

Comment: @j08691 I just updated the JSFiddle to give the div relative positioning. Sorry -- it was relatively positioned on my computer. Still no dice.

Comment: Not sure what the expected end result is. All the elements in the jsfiddle have top and left positions at 8 so `8 - 8 + "px"` is obviously `"0px"`.

Comment: @Juhana Note that when you comment out the `position = "absolute"` line `thing2` is given `left: 135px`. To my way of thinking, regardless of the positioning `left: 135px` should be applied because the `getBoundingClientRect` is being run on the element's static position either way. Adding `position = "absolute"` in a *later* line seems to affect a previous line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `#thing1` is statically positioned, it will appear at top-left.

And if `#thing2` is statically positioned too, it will be pushed to the right or to the next line by `#thing1`.

If `#thing1` is absolutely positioned with the box offset properties set to `auto`, it will appear at its static position, i.e. at the place it would be if it wasn't absolutely positioned. That is, at top-left.

But since it's absolutely positioned, it's taken out of flow. So it has no impact on later siblings. Therefore, `#thing2` will also appear at top-left, because it won't be pushed by `#thing1`.

What you can do is iterate backwards. This way, when you get the bounding rectangle, previous siblings won't be absolutely positioned yet, so they will push the current element.

```js
function changePosition(element){
  var dim = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
      pdim = element.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  element.style.left = dim.left - pdim.left + "px";
  element.style.top = dim.top - pdim.top + "px";
  element.style.position = "absolute";
}
changePosition(document.getElementById("thing2")); // First 2
changePosition(document.getElementById("thing1")); // Then 1
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="thing1" />
  <input id="thing2" />
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, my gosh, thank you so much. Can believe I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. `left` and `top` are set to 0 because you subtract the element's left from the parent element's left, which happen to be the same, so you end up with 0.

What actually happens in the example is that first, the first input is made absolute, which causes the second input to end up in the top left corner of the div, because the first no longer takes up space. Then the second one gets the first treatment as the first.

Solution: calculate the current positions first, then apply `position` to both of them.

Comment: @CupawnTae That's what Oriol said. I'm leaving my solution in, because it provides an alternative in case doing it the other way may not be feasible.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers explain the issue pretty well - by making `#thing1` absolute you take it out of the flow, thereby making `#thing2` jump to the left, so when you do its recalculation, it's over on the left as well.

One other solution is to defer the updates to the `position` property until after your code completes. You can do this with `setTimeout` with a delay of `0`

```
setTimeout(function(){
  instance.element.style.position = "absolute";
},0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oumt0nkv/10/